# Easy way to break foldl

Tags: erlang, fold

I need to break from foldl. Here is a dummy example how to break from fold when I count sum of values in a list and meet too big value (i.e. 10)

```
   L = [1,2,3,4,10,5,6,7],

   Res = 
      try
         lists:foldl(
            fun(I, Value) ->
               if (I < 10) ->
                  Value + I;
               true ->
                  throw({too_big_value, Value})
               end
            end,
            0, L)
      catch
         throw:{too_big_value, Value} -> Value
      end,

   Res.
```

I know this example is artificial but are there any nice method to break out fold (I know that fold always scan the whole structure)?

Please note, that i need to retrieve correct data even if i break from fold. In this case i should get data from previous iteration (as it done in my example).

Comment: What do you mean by "i need to retrieve correct data even if i break from fold"? Do you need the list with the changes made up to the throw?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're doing it right, using a throw with try/catch for nonlocal return. If the function looked at the return value from the fun to decide whether or not to continue, it wouldn't be foldl anymore.

Comment: Can you please answer a kind of philosophical question: "Is it fine to break from fold while it is not designed for it?" What is the better choice: 1) invent something (breaking fold) 2) writing more code (doing recursion)?

Comment: I think it's fine. The throw/catch adds very little overhead (certainly less than a corresponding fold-like function that takes a continue-or-not flag as part of the result from each function application), it's clear and readable, and you use a common idiom (foldl) rather than writing your own recursive function.

Answer (score 8):

Just curious, what is the point of using `foldl` here? If you need to break out, use recursion, `foldl` is not designed for it.

```
main([]) ->
  L = [1,2,3,4,5,10,6,7],

   io:format("[~w]", [s(L, 0)]).

s([], S) ->
  S;

s([H|T], S) ->
  if (H < 10) ->
    s(T, S + H);
  true ->
    S
  end.
```

**Update:**

Another options is to use `takewhile`:

```
lists:foldl(fun(E, A) -> A + E end, 0, lists:takewhile(fun(E) -> E < 10 end, L))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm trying to find the way to get more readable code. I'm newbie in Erlang and i'm trying to understand that is the better way to do smth. I suppose the your second variant is better than mine and your first one.

Comment: @usr Only second variant presumably creates additional list eating up memory (unless compiler can optimize it), while the first one does not.