# Folds versus recursion in Erlang

Tags: recursion, erlang, fold

According to [Learn you some Erlang](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/higher-order-functions#maps-filters-folds) :

> Pretty much any function you can think of that reduces lists to 1 element can be expressed as a fold. [...]
>   This means fold is universal in the sense that you can implement pretty much any other recursive function on lists with a fold

My first thought when writing a function that takes a lists and reduces it to 1 element is to use recursion.

What are the guidelines that should help me decide whether to use recursion or a fold?

Is this a stylistic consideration or are there other factors as well (performance, readability, etc.)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

folds are usually both more readable (since everybody know what they do) and faster due to optimized implementations in the runtime (especially foldl which always should be tail recursive). It's worth noting that they are only a constant factor faster, not on another order, so it's usually premature optimization if you find yourself considering one over the other for performance reasons.

Use standard recursion when you do fancy things, such as working on more than one element at a time, splitting into multiple processes and similar, and stick to higher-order functions (fold, map, ...) when they already do what you want.

Comment: I tested and found out that on an average the time taken by tail recursion is lesser than the time taken by foldl for the same list. Can someone explain why is that so?

Here is my code:
Recursion = fun(List) ->
 R = fun
  F([]) -> [];
  F([I | R]) -> [I*3 | F(R)]
 end,
 T1 = os:timestamp(),
 L1 = R(List),
 T2 = os:timestamp(),
 {L1, timer:now_diff(T2, T1) / 1000}
end.

Fold = fun(List) ->
 T1 = os:timestamp(),
 L1 = lists:foldl(
  fun(I, Acc) ->
   [I*3 | Acc]
  end, 
  [],
  List
 ),
 T2 = os:timestamp(),
 {L1, timer:now_diff(T2, T1) / 1000}
end.

Answer (score 8):

I personally prefer recursion over fold in Erlang (contrary to other languages e.g. Haskell). I don't see fold more readable than recursion. For example:

```
fsum(L) -> lists:foldl(fun(X,S) -> S+X end, 0, L).
```

or

```
fsum(L) ->
    F = fun(X,S) -> S+X end,
    lists:foldl(F, 0, L).
```

vs

```
rsum(L) -> rsum(L, 0).

rsum([], S) -> S;
rsum([H|T], S) -> rsum(T, H+S).
```

Seems more code but it is pretty straightforward and idiomatic Erlang. Using fold requires less code but the difference becomes smaller and smaller with more payload. Imagine we want a filter and map odd values to their square.

```
lcfoo(L) -> [ X*X || X<-L, X band 1 =:= 1].

fmfoo(L) ->
  lists:map(fun(X) -> X*X end,
    lists:filter(fun(X) when X band 1 =:= 1 -> true; (_) -> false end, L)).

ffoo(L) -> lists:foldr(
    fun(X, A) when X band 1 =:= 1 -> [X|A];
      (_, A) -> A end,
    [], L).

rfoo([]) -> [];
rfoo([H|T]) when H band 1 =:= 1 -> [H*H | rfoo(T)];
rfoo([_|T]) -> rfoo(T).
```

Here list comprehension wins but recursive function is in the second place and fold version is ugly and less readable.

And finally, it is not true that fold is faster than recursive version especially when compiled to native (HiPE) code.

**Edit**:
I add a fold version with fun in variable as requested:

```
ffoo2(L) ->
    F = fun(X, A) when X band 1 =:= 1 -> [X|A];
           (_, A) -> A
        end,
    lists:foldr(F, [], L).
```

I don't see how it is more readable than `rfoo/1` and I found especially an accumulator manipulation more complicated and less obvious than direct recursion. It is even longer code.

Comment: Don't forget `lists:zf/2`.  It's a mapfilter all in one.  With zf you can do `lists:zf(fun(X) when X band 1 =:= 1 -> {true, X * X}; (_) -> false end, L)`.  Unfortunately zf is not documented so does not officially exist...

Comment: Nice comparison of different methods! I think the fold is more readable in your first example, but the difference is of course pretty small with such a simple function. In your second example, I actually find fmfoo more readable than rfoo, but of course list comprehension wins big time for that problem. All of this shows that it's really up to the developer to pick the right tool for the job each time :-)

Comment: You find recursion more readable because you write foldl as oneliner. try putting the fun in a variable, it will look more readable than recursion.

Answer (score 2):

I expect fold is done recursively, so you may want to look at trying to implement some of the various list functions, such as map or filter, with fold, and see how useful it can be.

Otherwise, if you are doing this recursively you may be re-implementing fold, basically.

Learn to use what comes with the language, is my thought.

This discussion on foldl and recursion is interesting:

[Easy way to break foldl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412446/easy-way-to-break-foldl)

If you look at the first paragraph in this introduction (you may want to read all of it), he states better than I did.

http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~gmh/fold.pdf

Answer (score -1):

Old thread but my experience is that fold works slower than a recursive function.